# Search on mobile is driving me insane. Mag glass on click search box

Tags: css, mobile

I have some code below that i feel like should work just well but it appears to be breaking when i deploy.

All the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/82pmjqgn/

The search blob box just appearing over the content and not hidden. It should be hidden until it's clicked and then appear underneath. Here are some images for more reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    // Search

.block-search .amsearch-close,
.block-search .amsearch-loupe {
    top: 43px;
 }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .block-search .form .search-autocomplete {
        top: 43px;
    }

    .block-search .amsearch-close,
    .block-search .amsearch-loupe {
        top: 30%;
     }

}

.form .search-autocomplete {
    top: 88px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.block-search {
     
    
    .label {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
    input {
        border-radius: 50px;
        height: 40px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 44px;
    }
    .control {
        border-top: 0;
        clear:none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .action.search {
        background: #5a5a5a;
        border-radius: 50px;
        height: 34px;
        right: 4px;
        top: 3px;
        width: 34px;
    }
    .search-autocomplete ul:not(:empty) {
        border-color: #c2c2c2;
        border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    }
    .search-autocomplete ul {
        li {
            border-color: #c2c2c2;
            &:hover {
                background-color: #e5e5e5;
            }
            .amount {
                color: #444;
            }
        }
        .selected {
            background-color: #e5e5e5;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it currently looks.

[image: This is how it currently looks.]

[image]

How it should look.

Comment: Can you provide the hole code? how are we suppost to test it and see the problem?

Comment: Sure, you want the html as well?

Comment: @MiguelCruz are you available to still help?

Comment: Sure, but your css isn't working on fiddle...

Comment: Sorry about that... try now @MiguelCruz

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/82pmjqgn/

Comment: still not working :S